# I am getting an error that I am getting data in Form header instead of textbox

Tags: c#

This is the code in which I have getting data through clients connected via socket but I am getting my data in form header instead of textbox.

```
// Buffer for reading data
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[4096];
        String data = null;

       //Enter the listening loop
        while (true)
        {
            txtOutput.Text = "Waiting For Connection... to get started";

            //blocks until a client is connected to server
            TcpClient tcpClient = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            txtOutput.Text = "Connected!..";

            data = null;

            // Get a stream object for reading and writing
            NetworkStream netStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            int i;

            //loop to receive all data sent by the client
            while ((i = netStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
            {
                // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                //data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                //txtOutput.Text = data;

                ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(encoder.GetString(bytes, 0, 4096));



                Text += "\n" + Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes,0,i);
                txtOutput.Invoke(new Action(() => txtOutput.Text += text));

            }

            // Shutdown and end connection
            tcpClient.Close();


        }
```

[image: This is the form in question]

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Note that you were assigning data to `Text` before your invoke. Inside you invoke, you're trying to assign to your textbox the contents of `text`. This is not the same thing. Change the following line which is targeting your form's Text property as follows:

```
// Text += "\n" + Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes,0,i);
text += "\n" + Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes,0,i);
```

When assigning to the textbox in this line

```
txtOutput.Invoke(new Action(() => txtOutput.Text += text));
```

You were assigning from a `text` variable (small T) instead of the `Text` (big T) that you had placed your value in. The big T Text is the Text property of the form and will change your form header as you have said here.

Comment: Look at my answer now. I've changed it based on your comments and something else I saw in your code after reviewing it.

Comment: Note that in your code you're using a capital T to assign to text as in `Text += …` whereas you are then assigning to the textbox from `txtOutput.Text += text`. Case sensitivity makes these different objects. The Capital T one is the form's Text property, and the small t is a variable I assume you defines somewhere outside the code that you've shared.

Comment: I have corrected this but the issue remains the same